# In Django, how can I easily inherit a field and create a new class with this field preconfigured parameters?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am currently using UUID in my PostgreSQL database, therefore I am also using PrimaryKeyRelatedField() with some parameters in order to avoid problems when encoding to JSON the UUID field.
My serializer field looks like:

```
id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True,
                                   allow_null=False,
                                   pk_field=serializers.UUIDField(format='hex_verbose'))
```

And in every serializer that uses UUID I am having to use that.
My question is, how can I create a new class based on PrimaryKeyRelatedField so that I don't have to write all those parameters (read_only, allow_null...) ?

I am looking for something like:

```
id = BaseUUIDField()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make an abstract class using the id  which is a uuid field. Then inheret that model in your derived models.

```
import uuid
from django.db import models

 //Abstract Model
class AbstractModel(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True,default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)

    class Meta:
        Abstract =True

//Derived Model
class YourDerivedModel(Abstract.Model):
      //fields here
```

Hope this helps your query